# Driving backwards only a specific path EV3

Tags: lego-mindstorms-ev3

I'm currently working on a robot that can drive on lines. The robot needs to reverse sometimes.

I am generating the number of rotations randomly and use the same string on the reverse loop. Problem is that I want it to only drive back to the point where things went south, not all the way.

[image: The Problem. Should be clean]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.